# Reload DOM after changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have a small problem with SVG in an embed tag. I update the source of an embed tag with an SVG file path with javascript. Then I have to update the viewbox attribute to resize correctly the SVG.

The problem is that the SVG tag is not available because the javascript execution is too fast.

**An example :**

```
//Creation and insertion by JQuery
var EmbedTag = $("<embed id='zoomSVG' src=idSVG + ".svg' type='image/svg+xml' width='500px' height='500px' />").appendTo(zoomGalleryHisto);

//This doesn't work : svgDoc is null
//SVG document recovery
var svgDoc = document.getElementById('zoomSVG').getSVGDocument();

This work :
setTimeout(function(){
   //SVG document recovery
   var svgDoc = document.getElementById('zoomSVG').getSVGDocument();
},100);
```

I would like to not use the setTimeout function because the timeout value depend on hardware. Sometimes 100 ms works fine but I have to find an universal solution.

After embed tag insertion, could I reload the DOM by javascript ? Is an existing event for embed tag when the load of the embedded object is done ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the »onload« event of the  tag to delay your function until it is loaded, than the  should be available.

Comment: It is what I do but onload event doesn't catch with IE8

Comment: as Robert Longson mentioned above, IE8 does not support svg so your problem is with IE8 and SVG, what was not the question.

Answer (score 0):

Call the code from the onload of the embed e.g.

```
var EmbedTag = $("<embed id='zoomSVG' onload='init()' src=idSVG + ".svg' type='image/svg+xml' width='500px' height='500px' />").appendTo(zoomGalleryHisto);
```

and then implement your code in init (or whatever you want to call it)

Comment: IE8 does not support SVG natively

Comment: onload attribute is not on SVG tag but embed tag, SVG is supported by adobe plugin

Answer (score 0):

First, you create the element and then you trying to find it again in the DOM.

Second, javascript cant block until something happen, use callbacks insteed.

Something like that:

```
var svgDoc = false;
// Create an element
var EmbedTag = $("<embed id='zoomSVG' type='image/svg+xml' width='500px' height='500px' />");
// Append it to the dom
EmbedTag.appendTo(zoomGalleryHisto);

// Load the svg file
$.get('file.svg', function() {
    // And then add it to the created element
    EmbedTag.attr('src', 'file.svg');
    svgDoc = EmbedTag.getSVGDocument();
});
```

Comment: I don't load a SVG file with ajax, SVG file is loaded by embed tag

Comment: its the same! the embed tag should make a HTTP Request to retrieve the file. Now we retrieve it via get, cache it and then append it to the embed element.

Comment: yes but getSVGDocument return null, javascript is too fast. If I put a setTimeout between EmbedTag.attr('src', 'file.svg'); and svgDoc = EmbedTag.getSVGDocument(); it works